# How do I customize vimdiff colors?

Tags: colorscheme, vimdiff, color

I am trying to use vimdiff as my git merge tool, but the colors used are making it unbearable (at least on Windows/Mingw): the background color and the foreground color is the same for some of the conflicting lines, making it needlessly hard to figure out what is going on (see the lines below containing `include=`).

[image: example]

Comment: Just setting 'xterm 256 color' option in terminal will make the colors look better.

Comment: @balki Is that some setting I can universally set on the command line or is this different for every terminal emulator? I use Mac, Linux and WSL2

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The colors are controlled by these four highlight groups (`:help hl-DiffAdd`):

```
DiffAdd     diff mode: Added line
DiffChange  diff mode: Changed line
DiffDelete  diff mode: Deleted line
DiffText    diff mode: Changed text within a changed line
```

These are typically defined by a *color scheme*, but you can customize them in your `~/.vimrc` (after the `:colorscheme` command) if you like you scheme overall, just not its diff highlighting. Just redefine using `:highlight`. Here are my personal customizations (for GVIM; for the terminal you need the appropriate `ctermfg/bg=...` attributes instead / in addition):

```
hi DiffAdd      gui=none    guifg=NONE          guibg=#bada9f
hi DiffChange   gui=none    guifg=NONE          guibg=#e5d5ac
hi DiffDelete   gui=bold    guifg=#ff8080       guibg=#ffb0b0
hi DiffText     gui=none    guifg=NONE          guibg=#8cbee2
```

If you're switching colorschemes on the fly, you need to re-invoke those `:hi` commands via `:autocmd ColorScheme * hi ...`

Comment: A note for Neovim users confused why these highlight groups aren't working, you have to use `diffAdded`, `diffChanged`, and `diffRemoved`. Not sure what the nvim alternative to `DiffText` is - maybe `diffLine`?

Answer (score 49):

One quick fix is to disable syntax highlighting. Sometimes the code syntax highlighting will cause the foreground text to be the same color as the vimdiff background color, making the text "invisible".

`:syntax off`

If you want to automatically do this for vimdiff, then add this to the end of your `~/.vimrc`:

```
if &diff
    syntax off
endif
```

Comment: Simple and useful, thanks a lot, works like a charm!

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: Thanks so much, and +1! Had no clue why I couldn't see text that I definitely knew to be there until I switched `:syntax off`.

Comment: best answer, no need for too much work and if I `git mergetool` with `vim`, I don't need syntax highlighting!

Comment: the simplest way. thanks.

Answer (score 25):

[Extending Ingo Karkat's solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10898/21817) to terminal,

```
hi DiffAdd      ctermfg=NONE          ctermbg=Green
hi DiffChange   ctermfg=NONE          ctermbg=NONE
hi DiffDelete   ctermfg=LightBlue     ctermbg=Red
hi DiffText     ctermfg=Yellow        ctermbg=Red
```

Below are the `cterm-colors`, if you want to add your preferred color instead of the ones I used.

```
       NR-16   NR-8    COLOR NAME
        0       0       Black
        1       4       DarkBlue
        2       2       DarkGreen
        3       6       DarkCyan
        4       1       DarkRed
        5       5       DarkMagenta
        6       3       Brown, DarkYellow
        7       7       LightGray, LightGrey, Gray, Grey
        8       0*      DarkGray, DarkGrey
        9       4*      Blue, LightBlue
        10      2*      Green, LightGreen
        11      6*      Cyan, LightCyan
        12      1*      Red, LightRed
        13      5*      Magenta, LightMagenta
        14      3*      Yellow, LightYellow
        15      7*      White
```

Comment: this was so helpful I wish there was a +10 voting button

Answer (score 12):

Another quick (perhaps even lazy) fix is to just do something like:

```
:colo desert
```

This will change your color scheme, and in some cases will make hidden text become visible.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: That was the hint I was looking for.

Comment: `:colo` is short for `:colorscheme`. To get a list of available colour schemes other than `desert`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7331940/247696

Comment: To add a bit at this 'lazy' solution: Enter `:colo  ` then do TAB as many times as you want to see & test all possible schemes. My favorite dark theme is `industry`, and light theme: `shine`

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer didn't work for me. I'm using vim 8.2.
Add to .vimrc after 'colorscheme ...'

```
colorscheme challenger_deep

" Diff colors (Stand with Ukraine).
hi DiffAdded      ctermfg=Yellow    ctermbg=NONE
hi DiffRemoved    ctermfg=Blue      ctermbg=NONE
```

Changes against accepted answer:

- 'DiffAdded' instead of 'DiffAdd',
- 'DiffRemoved' instead of 'DiffDelete',
- Added in Yellow and remove in Blue.
- Color scheme: https://github.com/challenger-deep-theme/vim

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? These names are [hard-coded in Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/highlight.c#L225), and have ever since they're introduced. I can't really see how/why this works, unless that colourscheme does something very odd 

Comment: @MartinTournoij I'm not sure how it works but it really works in my version of vim. Colorscheme do not add new color groups. Using 'DiffAdd' do not work but 'DiffAdded' works for me.

Comment: Do you have a link to your colour scheme?

Comment: Sure. Here it is: https://github.com/challenger-deep-theme/vim

Comment: Will be interesting to figure out how this works

Comment: Ooo, thanks! My read on the situation: `DiffAdd` and friends have long been under `vimdiff` to highlight differences between buffers. Recently, I saw `DiffAdd` *also* start getting used under `set syntax=diff` to highlight lines starting with `+` and `-`. But I want the two to be different. So I kept my existing `DiffAdd` setting, and I changed `DiffAdded` (which I saw was being used under `set syntax=diff`, thanks to `syn list`, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168584/28465) to what I want there. (It's possible that things differ further across color schemes. I'm using a modified desert256.)

Comment: (And I guess that's controlled by https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/71d0ba07a33a750e9834cd42b7acc619043dedb1/runtime/syntax/diff.vim#L334-L338 and https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/71d0ba07a33a750e9834cd42b7acc619043dedb1/runtime/syntax/diff.vim#L383? But that file changed recently, including parts related to diffs. So I'm probably actually seeing an older version.)