# How to customize colorschemes without editing their source files?

Tags: colorscheme, plugin-system

Similarly to plug-ins, color schemes are commonly distributed as clone-able Git repositories, which make it less desirable to directly edit their source files (as sometimes suggested) when wanting to customize their behavior.

In the case of plug-ins, Vim offers the `after-directory` mechanism, which allows *personal preferences to overrule or add to the distributed defaults or system-wide settings*. For example, `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/fortran.vim`, if it exists, will automatically be read following the distributed `fortran.vim` while files in `after/plugin/` may be used in a similar way to customize individual plug-ins.

Unfortunately, this behaviour isn't supported for `colors/` as documented:

> `:colo[rscheme] {name}` searches `'runtimepath'` for the file `"colors/{name}.vim"`.
>
> The first one that is found is loaded.

Given that color schemes may be dynamically re-loaded (*e.g.* after setting `'background'`), simply patching it in `.vimrc` once it has been loaded is not enough. Furthermore, this does not scale well when managing many color schemes.

The documentation for `:colorscheme` suggests:

> To customize a colorscheme use another name, *e.g.* `~/.vim/colors/mine.vim`, and use `:runtime` to load the original colorscheme:
>
> ```
> runtime colors/evening.vim
> hi Statement ctermfg=Blue guifg=Blue
> ```

However, this is inconsistent with and seems less transparent than what is
described above (*e.g.* requiring another name). So, How can I can obtain
the automatic behavior of `after-directory` for color schemes?

---

Related:

- [How do I customize vimdiff colors?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10897)
- [Why do custom highlights in my vimrc get cleared or reset to default?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3355)
- [vim 8.0 not honoring custom colors](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12796)

On Stackoverflow:

- [How to set color after pathogen load colorscheme in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520433)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`AfterColors`](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1641) plug-in ([GitHub mirror](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AfterColors.vim)) provides an `after-directory` auto-loading mechanism for color schemes. This can however be easily achieved in modern Vim by using the `ColorScheme` autocommand event (triggered after loading a color scheme and added in [v7.0164](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b95186fd36bae9716181bfdd203fb27f410e3c4f)) and `<amatch>` (which holds the new color scheme name and was added in [v7.4.109](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b95186fd36bae9716181bfdd203fb27f410e3c4f)).

Therefore, the following command:

```
autocmd ColorScheme {pat} runtime "after/colors/" . expand("<amatch>") . ".vim"
```

will read `after/colors/{scheme}.vim` whenever the color scheme named `{scheme}`
(based on `g:colors_name`) is loaded, as long as `{sheme}` corresponds to the
globbing pattern `{pat}`. The pattern `*` can be used to match any scheme:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * runtime "after/colors/" . expand("<amatch>") . ".vim"
```

which also supports color schemes missing `after/colors/` custom scripts as
non-existing arguments aren't considered as errors by `runtime`. This one-liner allows you to structure your color scheme customization under your `after-directory` (typically `~/.vim/after/colors/`) by using a file per scheme.

As auto-commands obviously have to be declared before being called, make sure
to place the `autocmd` calls **before** calling `:colorscheme`, in your
`.vimrc`. Finally, multiple autocommands may listen to the same event and will be
triggered sequentially in the order in which they were defined so that:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * runtime "after/colors/" . expand("<amatch>") . ".vim"
autocmd ColorScheme * runtime "after/colors/common.vim"
colorscheme {scheme}
```

will read both `after/colors/{scheme}.vim` (if it exists) and `after/colors/common.vim`.

Similarly, sharing customization between schemes `{A}` and `{B}` may be done through

```
autocmd ColorScheme {A} runtime "after/colors/{B}.vim"
```

or by appending the following to `after/colors/{A}.vim`:

```
runtime "after/colors/{B}.vim"
```

but the former is more powerful given that a globbing pattern `{pat}` may be used.